# Using jQuery to dynamically position an element based on other elements

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to use jQuery to dynamically set a top position on a div that contains h3's. Linked is a image of what I am trying to accomplish.

In that picture, the top: on the titles div (green h3s) is absolute positioned with a hard coded top of 590. This works well if the tournament size never changes (8, 4, 2, 1)- but some tournaments only have two rounds (3 games) where the titles obviously fall way down the page.

In the brackets, I have added round-title-before and round-title-after classes to every halfway point so I can see/indicate that there is a title to be shown between them.

Is there a way to calculate with .position() or .height() the difference between .round-title-before and .round-title-after to correctly position the #title div so that it's always centered or close to center no matter how many or how few games there are? Second pic attached as example of a smaller tournament.

**Large Tournament:**

[image: Tournament Bracket]

========================

**Small Tournament:**

[image: Tournament Bracket Smaller]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use jqueryui's position functionality combined with putting each bracket in a container. The container will have a height that is equal to the total height, and you can use the aforementioned jqueryui position functionality to vertically centre (and I suppose to the right on the x axis) relative to the container.

Comment: Each round is contained in a div.bracket. But each bracket height is equal to the tallest one, because jQuery is also calcuclating positions to make the brackets line up through the championship evenly.

Comment: in this case I suppose you might consider declaring the parents of a bracket, and then calculating the offsets, using that to position. Are you able to post a jsfiddle by chance?